# How do I define my ENV variables?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables

I have the following configuration for both my production and development environments.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port      => 587,
  :user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
  :password  => ENV["MANDRILL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

I googled this for a while but I didn't find an answer that made me understand. How do I set the ENV variables both for development and for production for my rails project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're environment variables; you don't set them for development and production.

You can set application config variables in a variety of ways, or you can set them in the shell before running, or you can use environment-specific names, or...

Comment: so how do they work? and how can i set application config variables? I should better say where should I set the application config variables?

Comment: you can make use of JSON file or YAML file in a config folder to store the env. variables, to make it better understandable.

Comment: @Cody I want to be able to upload the app on github but I don't want to reveal the password... how do i do that ?

Comment: @MariusPop Don't want to reveal the password to *who*?

Comment: @DaveNewton well if I put my actual password instead of ENV["MANDRILL_PASSWORD"] and put it on github it will be public. I think I am not getting the big pucture... ?

Comment: @MariusPop Then use environment-specific ENV variable names and load up the appropriate ones in your config or something; any file-based solution will *also* be in github. Although the usecase for this somewhat escapes me; why not just tell people they need to configure their info, exactly as we all do in the database config?

Answer (score 2):

For development, you'll want to use a configuration file that is ignored in version control. It could be YAML, JSON, ruby, bash... it's a trivial choice. You'll then use an initializer file to make sure these variables are loaded when the app boots. For production, you can copy the config file (it may even have different settings) into the right place as part of your deploy process; or if you're using heroku, you can set these from command line using `heroku config:add YADA=yada`.

Here's a basic example with settings coming from a YAML file:

```
# config/settings.yml
development:
 MANDRILL_USERNAME=secret_username
 MANDRILL_PASSWORD=secret_password
 ANOTHER_SECRET_SETTING=the_list_goes_on_and_on
production:
 MANDRILL_USERNAME=different_username
 MANDRILL_PASSWORD=another_password
 ANOTHER_SECRET_SETTING=get_the_idea?

# .gitigore
# ...
config/settings.yml

# config/initializers/environment_settings.rb
environment_settings = YAML.load_file('./config/settings.yml')[Rails.env]
environment_settings.each do |key, value|
  ENV[key] ||= value
end
```